# Angularjs ui router ui-sref generate wrong url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Trying to switch between child views, however ui-sref generate a wrong url when the other child is already loaded.
The correct link: 'template/viewname.html'
The actual link: 'home/template/viewname.html'
How to stop ui-sref from adding 'home/' to the link ?
Thanks

app

```
 angular.module('app',[,'ngRoute','ui.router']);
```

config

```
angular.module('app').config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider',    '$locationProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider,    $locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'template/index.html',
    controller: 'contr'

})
.state('home.about', {
    parent:'home',
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: 'template/about.html',
    controller: 'contr'

})
.state('home.contact', {
    parent: 'home',
    url: '/contact',
    templateUrl: 'template/contact.html',
    controller: 'contr'

})  }]);
```

Home page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Home</h3>
   <div>
     <a ui-sref="home.about">abouttt</a>
     <a ui-sref="home.contact">contact</a>
   </div>
   <div ui-view>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a small plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/RbjGt8zhAGSRb00idkEU?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
 })

  $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
})
.state('home.about', {
    parent:'home',
    url: '/about',
   views:{
      '@':{
        'templateUrl': '/tpl1.html'
      }
    }
    //controller: 'contr'

})
```

Answer (score 2):

You're shooting yourself in the foot:

- you set requireBase to false, instead of using the default. The reason for the base tag is precisely that it allows relative URLs to be treated as relative to the base URL, rather than to the current URL
- despite your choice to not use a base tag, you still use relative URLs, instead of absolute ones (i.e. URLs starting with `/, and which thus always point to the same location whatever the current location is).

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#relative-links for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use absolute URLs in your `templateUrl`, i.e. with a leading slash. For example:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/template/index.html',
    controller: 'contr'
});
```